# Zip with tuples and list

Tags: python, string, list, zip, tuples

I need to write a code that will return the characters of two strings as a list of tuples. The code should stop when either one of the strings runs out of characters. I know is a simple code but I cannot get to work where it gives me more than just the first character.

it should look like this:

```
>>> twoStrings('Good', 'Morning') 
[('G', 'M'), ('o', 'o'), ('o', 'r'),('d', 'n')]
```

so far this is the code I have

```
def twoStrings(string1,string2):
    for i in zip(string1,string2):
        return [i]
```

but if I try to run it I only get this back:

```
[('G', 'M')]
```

can you please help me?

Comment: You're returning way too early.

Comment: You're describing the `zip` function. Just use it directly.

Comment: Did you realize `zip` is already returning the list you want? You do not need any loop here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correct your code, here is the fix:

```
def twoStrings(string1,string2):
        return zip(string1,string2)
```

Comment: Please, whoever down-voted should leave a comment as a reason for his down-vote!

Comment: It's not me but you are unpacking the list returned by `zip` simply to repack it. `twoStrings = zip` does the exact same thing as your function and is a lot faster.

Comment: ok I see...thanks thoughh...it was only to fix OP code...didn't looked at optimization

Answer (score 4):

This may be as simple as simply using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) on the two given strings.

```
print zip('Good', 'Morning')
>>> [('G', 'M'), ('o', 'o'), ('o', 'r'), ('d', 'n')]
```